# xlsxwriter AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'add_worksheet'

Tags: python, directory, xlsxwriter

I'm trying to write a python script where I add multiple worksheets to an excel document and each sheet's name is the name of a folder and I keep getting the error "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'add_worksheet'"

Here is a sample of my code:

```
import os
import xlsxwriter

directory = r"D:\Work\Folders"
workbook = (r"D:\Work\Folders\Data.xlsx")



for folder in os.listdir(directory):
    workbook = ("Data.xlsx")
    workbook.add_worksheet(folder)
    print (folder)
```

Its simple but I cant seam to figure out what the issue is.

Comment: Welcome to SO.   Fwiw, ```workbook``` is a string since you've set it in ```workbook = ("Data.xlsx")```.   you're not using xlswriter at all.  Did you intend to do ```workbook = xlswriter.Workbook("Data.xlsx")```?  And you also don't need to put ```workbook = ...``` inside the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At no point in your code are you utilizing `xlsxwriter`. You simply iterate over a directory and try to use a `add_worksheet` method on a string, as the traceback shows. Just wrapping `"Data.xlsx"` in a tuple does not magically make it an Excel workbook. You will need to check the documentation for how to use `xlsxwriter` and how to open files with it.